# Visible Grid appearing in Image in PDF

Tags: pdf, cmyk, print-production

I have a .pdf that I am trying to send to our printer which has a few color images in the manuscript.  These few high resolution images are appearing to have a weird grid in them that was not present before. What is causing the appearance of this grid and how can I get rid of it?

[image: pictures with grid boxes that shouldn't be there]

Also, I pulled down the proof and looked at with Acrobat Pitstop combo and I am realizing that the images are quite massive.  It's telling me that the image is a collection of images (each one in the grid box is a separate image that each have something like 900 x 900 px.  Could this be relevant?
[image]

Comment: Is it bad to accidentally ask a duplicate question?  Seems like one answer (yours) covered two different manifestations of a _similar_ problem.  But is this why the questions are now linked, to guide users to the solution but expanding the ways they could get there?

Comment: Maxwell, it's not "bad" to ask a duplicate. It happens. Duplicates are closed to prevent repetitive content.  If an answer has already been provided, there's not a great deal of value in repeating the answer.

Comment: In addition, others are always encourage to add answers to the original (duplicate) question. It just so happens in this case, no one else added an answer. But they still can.

Comment: Sure, sure - but does my question remain searchable and findable on the site / search engines?